# How to prevent ReactSelect from clearing the input?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The ReactSelect component in my app is clearing what I have typed after I make a selection. I don't want it to do that.

I want it to leave it as is. When the user has not entered anything, I want it to show the Placeholder text.

I'm using this component as a search box. Selecting an item from the list accomplishes the task. There's no reason to set the component's value to the selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-select` does not support autocompletion out of the box so it requires a bit of extra work and hacks to get what you want.

First off, you need to control the `inputValue` state, some operations like `menu-close` or `set-value` will clear the input afterward.

```js
const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
const handleInputChange = (e, meta) => {
  if (meta.action === "input-change") {
    setInput(e);
  }
};

return (
  <Select
    value={selected}
    onChange={handleChange}
    inputValue={input}
    isSearchable
    {...}
  />
);
```

`react-select` also hides the input after an option is selected so you also need to override that behavior as well.

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
const handleChange = (s) => {
  setSelected({ ...s });
};

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const inputEl = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (!inputEl) return;
  // prevent input from being hidden after selecting
  inputEl.style.opacity = "1";
}, [selected]);

return (
  <Select
    value={selected}
    inputId="myInput"
    onChange={handleChange}
    {...}
  />
);
```

Last but not least, you may want to update your input accordingly after a successful selection, here is a basic example, the code below will append the new option value to your current input after a selection.

Also make sure to override the default `filterOption` to only taking into account the last word when filtering or nothing will match with the options after the first few words.

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
const handleChange = (s) => {
  setSelected({ ...s });
  setInput((input) => removeLastWord(input) + s.value);
};

const customFilter = () => {
  return (config, rawInput) => {
    const filter = createFilter(null);
    return filter(config, getLastWord(rawInput));
  };
};

return (
  <Select
    value={selected}
    filterOption={customFilter()}
    onChange={handleChange}
    inputValue={input}
    components={{
      SingleValue: () => null
    }}
    {...}
  />
);
```

Where `removeLastWord` and `getLastWord` are just some utility functions.

```js
function getLastWord(str: string) {
  return str.split(" ").slice(-1).pop();
}

function removeLastWord(str: string) {
  var lastWhiteSpaceIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
  return str.substring(0, lastWhiteSpaceIndex + 1);
}
```

Here is a complete example after combining all of the above.

```
import React from "react";
import Select, { components, createFilter } from "react-select";
import options from "./options";

function getLastWord(str: string) {
  return str.split(" ").slice(-1).pop();
}

function removeLastWord(str: string) {
  var lastWhiteSpaceIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
  return str.substring(0, lastWhiteSpaceIndex + 1);
}

export default function MySelect() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = (s) => {
    setSelected({ ...s });
    setInput((input) => removeLastWord(input) + s.value);
  };
  const handleInputChange = (e, meta) => {
    if (meta.action === "input-change") {
      setInput(e);
    }
  };

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const inputEl = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (!inputEl) return;
    // prevent input from being hidden after selecting
    inputEl.style.opacity = "1";
  }, [selected]);

  const customFilter = () => {
    return (config, rawInput) => {
      const filter = createFilter(null);
      return filter(config, getLastWord(rawInput));
    };
  };

  return (
    <Select
      value={selected}
      filterOption={customFilter()}
      inputId="myInput"
      onChange={handleChange}
      blurInputOnSelect={false}
      inputValue={input}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      options={options}
      isSearchable
      hideSelectedOptions={false}
      components={{
        SingleValue: () => null
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit React - react-select Simple Autocomplete]

Comment: Wow, you did so much work to help me. Thank you. But having tried your demo, I fear that you may have solved a different problem. It doesn't do what I want. 

In your demo, I type "z" and then select Uzbekistan. I want the contents of the box to remain "z", but the contents change to "Uzbekistan".

Comment: All set. The part of your solution about setting the opacity was all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You made my day

Comment: thanks, I did some changes and it's working like charme

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the input styles using the `styles` props. There is a whole discussion about this issue on this [thread](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3068)

```
{
  input: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    input: {
      opacity: "1 !important",
    },
  }),
}
```